# Add titles to items from array

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, foreach

I don't have that much experience with PHP and am looking for help with the following:

I am fetching data from an SQL table that has a column "`countries`" containing the name of a country and a column "`desc`" containing a comment.

On my web page I create an array out of the matching countries (based on certain criteria) in order to sort them alphabetically and to add an image in front of each of them (images have the same name as the countries). 
Finally I am just echoing out this array in order to display the countries and corresponding images on the page. 
All of this works well so far (using the below code).

**My code:**

```
$countries = '';
$valC = '';
$countC = 0;
foreach ($objDays->days as $days) {
    if(($days->dateMatch == "Yes") && ($days->locales != "")) {
        $inputC[] = explode(',', $days->locales);
        $countC++;
    }
}
if($countC == 0) {
    $countries = "&nbsp;<img src='images/icons/emotion_what.png' alt='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;No data on file for this date.";
} else {
    $arrC = array_map("trim", call_user_func_array("array_merge", $inputC));
    sort($arrC);
    array_walk($arrC, function (&$valC) { $valC = "<img src='images/icons/flags-32/flag_" . str_replace(" ", "_", $valC) . ".png' alt='' id='c" . $valC . "' style='width:32px' />&nbsp;" . $valC; } );
    $countries = implode(' &nbsp;&nbsp;', $arrC);
}
// ...
echo $countries;
```

**Update:** 
The `explode` is no longer needed as now there is always only one country in each cell of the table.

**What I am unable to do is the following:** 
I would like to add also the the comments from my column "`desc`" as a (hover) title to each country that I am echoing out. 
I can fetch this via `$objDays->days->desc` resp. `$days->desc` but can't find a way to add this in.

Can someone here help me with this ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be as simple as adding `$objDays->days->desc`  to the `alt` attribute of the image?

Comment: Thanks. This doesnt work because of the foreach loop I use in the beginning. I guess I somehow need to define which desc belongs to which country, no ?

Comment: This question would be clearer with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a sub array inside $inputC like that :

```
foreach ($objDays->days as $days) {
    if(($days->dateMatch == "Yes") && ($days->locales != "")) {
        $inputC[] = array(
            "text" => explode(',', $days->locales),
            "desc" => $days->desc
        );
        $countC++;
    }
}
```

And modify your array_walk

```
array_walk($arrC, function (&$valC) { $valC = "<img src='images/icons/flags-32/flag_" . str_replace(" ", "_", $valC['text']) . ".png' alt='".$valC['desc']."' id='c" . $valC['text'] . "' style='width:32px' />&nbsp;" . $valC['text']; } );
```

edit : Your trim & array_merge will be certainly broken and need to be updated.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thanks a lot for the quick reply ! One more question on this: As the explode is now not needed anymore (as per my update) would this affect your answer ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do I have to replace 'name' with 'text' and add the square brackets to all $valC in your last line ?

Comment: Oops, yes, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks ! Let me test again

Comment: I am getting the following error which refers to the trim in my else statement: Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\calendarCheck\index.php on line 95

Comment: I will post my last question separately - thanks again !